# post label value or table cell value or hidden text value in php

Tags: php, javascript, html

This is a simple problem. I am working on a PHP project related to customers and vendors. When I select `customerid` from the database, unpaid bills of that customer populate automatically in a table, so table contains a check, the bill number, the bill amount, the paid amount, and a "remove" column.

This remove link will remove that row, so that I can pay only for some bills. (If I have 5 unpaid bills, I could remove 3 bills and enter the data for the other 2 bills). Here I want to show `billno` and `billamount` as labels, and the payment amount as a textbox for entering the amount. I need to post the `billno` to the server because I may remove some rows. But `$_POST` of PHP doesn't recognize a label. I tried with a `td` id (table cell id) and  input type "hidden" but that didn't work. Can you suggest a way to do this?

Here is my code:

Table code:

```
    <TABLE id="mytable1">
     <tr>
     <th>Select</th>
     <th>Bill No</th>
     <th>Bill Amount</th>
     <th>Received Amount</th>
     <th>Remove</th>
     </tr>
  <TR>
  <td ><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk[]" ></td>        
  <td ><label id="labelidinv"></label><input type="hidden" name="invhide[]" value="12" ></td>
  <TD><label id="labelidinvamt"></label> </TD>
  <TD><input name="receivedamt[]" type="text" size="6" id="receivedamt" ></TD>
  <td> <a href="#" onClick="deleteRowReceipt('mytable1')">Remove </a> </td>
  </TR>
</table>
```

Ajax code:

```
    var inv_id = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("inv_id");
    var inv_amt = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("inv_amt");
    var count = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("count");
    var inv_id_desc = inv_id[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
    var inv_amt_desc = inv_amt[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
    var countdesc = count[0].firstChild.nodeValue;

   document.getElementById('labelidinv').innerHTML =inv_id_desc;
   document.getElementById('labelidinvamt').innerHTML=inv_amt_desc;                                                                                      
             var table = document.getElementById('mytable1');
                    for(var j=1;j<countdesc;j++)
                    {
                        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
                        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
                        var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

                        for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++)
                        {

                  var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
                           newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;
                              if(i==1)
                               newcell.innerHTML =   inv_id[j].firstChild.nodeValue;                
                              if(i==2)
                                newcell.innerHTML= inv_amt[j].firstChild.nodeValue;

                        }
                    }
```

Here I am not able to post label id values. Is there any way to do it like that? I want the read only values in labels, and I need to post them back to server. Thanks in advance.

Edit

I am sending ajax request like this

```
 var custname = document.getElementById('customer').options[document.getElementById('customer').selectedIndex].value;

 xmlhttp.open("POST","../MODEL/AjaxRequestHandler.php?action=custdetails&CUST_NAME="+custname,true)
```

At AjaxRequestHandler page:

```
        $CUST_NAME = $_GET['CUST_NAME'];
        $querry1 = "select * from RECEIVABLES where CUSTOMER_NAME = $cust_name and FULL_PART_PAID !='F' and voucher_type='SI' ";
/*full_part_paid column is whether that bill fully paid or not, and voucher type = "Sales invoice"*/
        $res1 = odbc_exec($conn,$querry1);
        $i = 0;
        echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'."\n";
                echo '<XmlResponse>'. "\n";
                while(odbc_fetch_row($res1))
                {
                    $inv_id= odbc_result($res1, "invoice_id");
                    echo '<inv_id>'.$inv_id.'</inv_id>'. "\n";
                    $inv_amt = odbc_result($res1,"invoice_amount");
                    echo '<inv_amt>'.$inv_amt.'</inv_amt>'. "\n";
                    $i++;

                }
                echo '<count>'.$i.'</count>'."\n";

        echo '</XmlResponse>'. "\n";
```

Comment: I would recommend you go back and revisit some of your previous questions for further assistance. If you need help with your previous questions and aren't getting enough traction on them, visit chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5/the-so-tavern-general and ask for help with your questions. The community here is about solving questions and marking them accepted, so that future askers may be able to see what worked for you and not need to ask their own questions. I'm happy to help as I may.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am understanding what you are trying to do, then here's my suggestion:

Change

```
<input name="receivedamt[]" type="text" size="6" id="receivedamt">
```

to:

```
<input name="receivedamt_<?= $row['id'] ?>" type="text" size="6" id="receivedamt_<?= $row['id'] ?>">
```

where `$row['id']` is the actual ID of this database row. That way, when the postdata comes in, you will be able to know what rows are paid as follows:

```
<?php

foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $key_parts = explode('_',$key);
    if($key_parts[0] == 'receivedamt' && !empty($value) {
      $id = intval($key_parts[1]);
      $amt = doubleval($value);
      mysql_query("UPDATE `some_table` SET `receivedamt`=$amt WHERE `id`=$id");
    }
}
```

That way, you don't even have to worry about the checkboxes or deleting the rows. Just leave any payments you don't want to pay blank, and the server will not update them. Or, delete the rows from the DOM if you prefer, the server will still not update them because they won't be sent in `$_POST`.

Does that make sense?

Comment: thanks for the response. But i am not able to understand this, i am using db2, and from where did i get this $row['id'], can you elaborate a little bit more?? Thanks in advance and thanks for editing the question.

Comment: @jony: Please edit your question and share the code for how you are selecting data out of the database now, and I will edit my answer to match.

Comment: i added the required information for you, pls have a look at that. thanks.

Comment: Ok... you're making this much more complicated than it needs to be. Can I ask why you're populating the table via AJAX rather than just generating the table in PHP?

Comment: this is bill payment page, so from drop down list of customer names, i select one name and his unpaid his bills. That's why i am using ajax

Answer (score 1):

One way to get around this problem is not to delete the rows of paid bills, which is bad practice anyway. Why are you deleting the record of the bill that was paid...what if a problem arises and you need to confirm past payments? Instead, I would add a column to the table for "paid" and change the value from 0 to 1 when a payment goes through. Then you don't have to send the labels back to the server, and can just pull the data for bills with a "paid" value of 0 for display on the pay site.

Comment: This is called "accounting" ;) ... seriously tho, I agree and recommend the OP to become much more acquainted with double entry ledger accounting.

Comment: I *think* he's talking about removing `<table><tr>` rows, *not mysql rows*. But, I could be mistaken...

Comment: @Josh - you are correct, just i am removing the rows from table, not from database.